# Calculate a 3D vector out of another vector and a rotation

Tags: javascript, vector, 3d, three.js

So this is a kind of difficult question. I am using `three.js` and I need to calculate a specific vector.
I have one vector (let's call it `C`) and I have a rotation `(r)` in form of an `euler`. Now I want to calculate a second vector `(X)`, that, minus itself `(X)` with the rotation `euler` applied, would equal the first vector.
So in pseudo code:

```
X - X(r) = C
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, read about [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert `euler` into a 3x3 matrix. Note that `three.js` uses [*Tait-Bryan* angles](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Euler.order) rather than *Proper Euler* angles. Construct the required matrix `R` from [these axis rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations) by multiplying in the order `Rz * Ry * Rx`.
2. Note that `X = I * X` where `I` is the 3x3 identity matrix.
3. The equation becomes `(I - R) * X = C`, which is simple to invert: `X = inverse(I - R) * C`. ([Matrix3.getInverse](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Matrix3.getInverse))

---

EDIT: how to compute `R`:

- Use standard rotation matrices:

  [image]
- For `euler = (x, y, z)`, `R = Rz(z) * Ry(y) * Rx(x)`:

  ```
  var c_x = Math.Cos(euler.x), s_x = Math.Sin(euler.x);
  var Rx = (new Matrix3()).set(
            1,   0,    0,
            0, c_x, -s_x,
            0, s_x,  c_x
           );
  // and similarly with Ry and Rz
  ```
- Finally:

  ```
  var R = Rz.multiply(Ry.multiply(Rx));
  var ImR = (new Matrix3()).set(
             1.0 - R.elements[0], -R.elements[1], -R.elements[2],
             -R.elements[3], 1.0 - R.elements[4], -R.elements[5],
            -R.elements[6], -R.elements[7], 1.0 - R.elements[8]
            );
  // multiply ImR.getInverse() with C to get X
  ```

Comment: Thanks. Could you go into detail about how to construct the matrix?

Comment: @JannisX11 if you have difficulty understanding the links I gave, then yes I'll post shortly.

Comment: That would be nice. I haven't used matrices a lot.